# Get total size for a list of tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a prod database that is very large in size. I need to copy this DB to make a test environment, however there is not enough disk space.

But actually there is no need to copy rows from tables containing user-data, only those tables that describe functionality are necessary. For tables with user-data I only need to copy table "description" (columns, indexes, triggers, ...).

How (with what query) can I estimate the size of DB without data from some tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) 

-- DB size.
EXEC sp_spaceused

-- Table row counts and sizes.
CREATE TABLE #t 
( 
    [name] NVARCHAR(128),
    [rows] CHAR(11),
    reserved VARCHAR(18), 
    data VARCHAR(18), 
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
) 

INSERT #t EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 

SELECT *
FROM   #t

-- # of rows.
SELECT SUM(CAST([rows] AS int)) AS [rows]
FROM   #t

DROP TABLE #t
```

**by Alexander Groß **
[Link to source](http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,df930155-f60f-4f56-ab33-f1352ff091a1.aspx)

Comment: @xaxa Execute this script in you database context database for which you want all the information. It gives you a detailed Report about Database , all the tables in that database etc etc

Comment: I have mentioned the authors name, I have been told in the past that  pasting hyperlinks in answers is not a good practice.

Comment: I would strongly suggest avoiding sp_MSForEachTable. It was written with the same logic as sp_MSForEachDB, which is notorious for skipping databases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 for the suggestion. much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

```
  SELECT 
    schema_qualified_table = s.name + '.' + t.name, 
    KB = SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) * 8192/1024.0 
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
  ON t.[object_id] = ps.[object_id]
  WHERE s.name + '.' + t.name IN   (N'dbo.table1', N'dbo.table2', ...) 
  -- list of tables you do care about ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^
  GROUP BY s.name + '.' + t.name;
```

A little tidier might be:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT o = t.[object_id], n = s.name + '.' + t.name
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
)
SELECT 
    schema_qualified_table = x.n, 
    KB = SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) * 8192/1024.0
  FROM x INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
  ON x.o = ps.[object_id]
  WHERE x.n IN (N'dbo.table1', N'dbo.table2', ...);
```

Comment: I would expand this to include schemas in your output,  in case you have identically named tables in multiple schemas.

Comment: @Andrew sure, go ahead

Comment: @Andrew Code in a comment is really hard to read. And see, while normally I agree, the reason I didn't go that far, is because what if the OP wants `dbo.foo` and `other_schema.foo`, and `dbo.bar` but *not* `other_schema.bar`. The WHERE clause suddenly gets a lot more complex and we don't even know if the OP has more than one schema, never mind the situation where they have placed identical table names under different schemas. This is usually an accident based on users with different default schemas and not specifying schema when creating objects.

Comment: yes, that code came out really funky in the comment.  I agree that trying to start specifying combinations of schemas and tables in your where clause could get ugly.  But if the OP did have schemas with the same table name, not including the schema in the group by will potentially significantly inflate the reported size of the table.  (Did that make sense?)

Comment: @Andrew yes, that makes sense, but again if you want that to be clear in your answer, you should address the scenario and mention that the WHERE clause could become an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Posting my expansion to Aaron Bertrand's answer, just for readability.  Only difference is adding the join to the SCHEMAS table, and including schema name in the output and group by.

```
  SELECT 
   s.name,
    t.name, 
    KB = SUM(ps.reserved_page_count) * 8192/1024.0 
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps
  ON t.[object_id] = ps.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas S
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
  WHERE t.name IN (<YOUR TABLES GO HERE) -- list of tables you do care about
  GROUP BY t.name,
  s.name;
```

As Aaron has rightly pointed out, trying to filter on a combination of tables and schemas could get ugly very fast.  You could easily end up with a huge collection of ORs:

```
(S.SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA1' and T.NAME = 'FOO')
OR
(S.SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA2' and T.NAME = 'FOO')
OR
(S.SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA1' and T.name = 'BAR')
...
```

Comment: use `ps.used_page_count`  instead of `ps.reserved_page_count` for used data (data + index_size)... basically do not count unused data.